# how to interchage image banners randomly when page refresh?

Tags: javascript, arrays, random, velocity

here are my banners:

[image]

pls help me with this.
i want that when the page loads, every banners exchange places in any order.

i am using apache velocity for this but i just want to know the logic on how to code it. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your banner are images, you could create a JS array with all your images, [randomize](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2450976/5878195) it and then change your `img` sources.

For exemple :

```
<img id="banner1" src="" />
<img id="banner2" src="" />
<img id="banner3" src="" />

<script>
    var images = ["http://exemple.com/banner1", "http://exemple.com/banner2", "http://exemple.com/banner3"];
    images = shuffle(images);
    $('#banner1').attr('src', images[0]);
    $('#banner2').attr('src', images[1]);
    $('#banner3').attr('src', images[2]);

function shuffle(array) {
  var currentIndex = array.length, temporaryValue, randomIndex;

  // While there remain elements to shuffle...
  while (0 !== currentIndex) {

    // Pick a remaining element...
    randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
    currentIndex -= 1;

    // And swap it with the current element.
    temporaryValue = array[currentIndex];
    array[currentIndex] = array[randomIndex];
    array[randomIndex] = temporaryValue;
  }

  return array;
}
</script>
```

Comment: Nope, sorry @JasmineGalang

Comment: thanks @Gwendal! it worked! ill just convert it to velocity. hopefully i can do it. haha